# ERROR in [eslint], Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," - React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I recently installed TypeScript and Jest in our React app, but when I run 'npm start', I encounter a series of parser-related errors. Unexpected tokens 'extends' and 'as' in TypeScript are being reported. Here are my configuration files:

Package.json:

```
... "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
        "build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=8000 build",
        "lint": "eslint .",
        "lint:fix": "eslint --fix .",
        "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,md,html,css,less,scss}\"",
        "test": "jest",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "plugin:react/recommended",
            "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
            "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
        ],
        "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
        "plugins": [
            "@typescript-eslint"
        ],
        "parserOptions": {
            "ecmaVersion": 2020,
            "sourceType": "module",
            "ecmaFeatures": {
                "jsx": true
            }
        },
        "env": {
            "browser": true,
            "es6": true
        },
        "globals": {
            "$": true
        },
        "settings": {
            "react": {
                "version": "^17.0.1"
            }
        },
        "overrides": [
            {
                "files": [
                    "*.ts",
                    "*.tsx"
                ],
                "parserOptions": {
                    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
                }
            }
        ],
        "rules": {
            "semi": [
                "error",
                "never"
            ]
        }
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "resolutions": {
        "moment": "2.29.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.23.3",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "12.1.5",
        "@types/jest": "^29.5.10",
        "@types/node": "^20.10.0",
        "@types/react": "^18.2.38",
        "@types/react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.7",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.17",
        "@types/react-paginate": "^7.1.4",
        "@types/testing-library__react": "^10.2.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.13.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.13.1",
        "eslint-config-standard-react": "^9.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.6",
        "jest": "^29.7.0",
        "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
        "prettier": "^2.1.1",
        "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "typescript": "^5.3.2"
    } ...
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["node", "jest", "@testing-library/jest-dom", "react", "react-dom"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": [
    "./dist/**/*",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
    }
  }
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-react",
        ["@babel/preset-env", { "targets": { "node": "current" } }],
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
      ],
      "plugins": ["@emotion"]
}
```

I tried searching for other posts, but I couldn't resolve the issue with the proposed solutions